# Stored procedure in SQL - change output

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a report which will pull the data from this stored procedure

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT Empname
FROM  EmpComp

UNION

SELECT ('NULL') AS Empname
```

The values are returned correctly. But dropdownlist is showing `NULL` in the middle of other datas.I want `NULL` as first value in the drop downlist(so that easy for selecting).This stored prcedure is connected to a dataset(in report) which have one parameter (Empname).

How can I amend above code for that? Thanks

Comment: try this `SELECT ('NULL') AS Empname  UNION  SELECT Empname FROM EmpComp`

Comment: @JSantosh that would give the same result. Note that NULL is selected as string value and not NULL keyword.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

This works :) Idea is to select Empname with NULL keyword on top and then transform values to string types.

```
select case when Empname is null then 'NULL' else Empname end 
from
(
    select null as Empname
    union
    select Empname from EmpComp
) a
```

Comment: Thanks,        This stored prcedure is connected to a dataset(in report) which have one parameter (Empname).After executing the above code,The parameter Empname is changed to ID,which cause error in report.
The stored procedure must return one paramenter which is Empname.
[In the query designer it is working.(Null is showing first. but when preview the report,error is showing]